# Continuous quoting overline?

Tags: quoting, csquotes

I am trying to use the `csquotes` package, but have found a problem.

If I type

```
\foreignquote{french}{Take for example the work of demonstrating a 
theorem which remains hypothetical (to which, for cetain people, the 
mathematic work seems to reduce).

some other words}
```

then I get [image: screenshot I].

But, if I want to suppress the second starting quotation mark, as the following picture shows, what should I use?

[image: screenshot II]
I tried all `visibly` available options in the package manual, as well as the triad *quote*, *quotaion*, and *verse*, but to no avail, so I turned to this site, in the hope that someone might know something that can handle this situation.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. The second picture is taken from the article *Quelques idées maîtresses de l’œuvre de A. Grothendieck* by ***Pierre Deligne,*** of which the first is a screen-shot of a rough attempt at the translation.

Comment: I can't speak for French, but I beleive it is the style in English for a quote extending into a new paragraph to repeat the opening quote mark (and omit the closing quote mark, if quote will continue into new paragraph).

Comment: I see that there is such a tradition, but I am trying to imitate the style of the article in question, which seems natural as well. Still thanks for the opinion.